# Saving post from textarea to database in Razor pages WebApplication

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-applications, razor-pages

I'm trying to build a social network on a ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio.
There is membership and a wall, where members can make posts.
I'm using Tinymce for a `textarea` with editing tools, and I'm supposed to save the text in the `textarea` in HTML form to my local Visual Studio database, along with the `UserId` of the connected user who is posting.

When I run the application and try to post, neither of these seem to work. I'm getting a `null` entry in the database for both the `Text` and the `UserId`.

While `UserManager` works properly on the `.cshtml` file and does return the `UserId`, I can't get it to work on the `.cs` file

Related code so far, of the `.cshtml` file:

```html
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
    @inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
    @model IndexModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    }
    <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="UploadFiles" asp-action="Index">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>You are connected and can post as @UserManager.GetUserId(User)</p>
            <textarea name="txt" id="mytextarea" rows="2" cols="80" asp-for="Posts.Text" >
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Related code of the `.cs` file:

```
    private readonly proj.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(proj.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }    
    public Models.Posts Posts { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        UserManager<Data.ApplicationUser> UserManager;
        var post = new Models.Posts {UserId = UserManager.GetUserId(User), Text = Posts.Text };
        _context.Posts.Add(post);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Page();
    }
```

I get an "unassigned local variable" error for `UserManager`.
Can you please help me get the content of the `textarea` correctly, and define `UserManager` properly?

Comment: Could you show the code from `UserManager` class?

Comment: It's not my own class. It's a class from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have used **Depend injection** so you can try *constructor* injection

```
private readonly proj.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

private UserManager<Data.ApplicationUser> _userMannger;

public IndexModel(proj.Data.ApplicationDbContext context, 
   UserManager<Data.ApplicationUser> user)
{
   _userMannger= user;
    _context = context;
}   
public Models.Posts Posts { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var post = new Models.Posts {UserId = _userMannger.GetUserId(User), Text = Posts.Text };
    _context.Posts.Add(post);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Page();
}
```

Comment: I tried that before. I get "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'store' of 'UserManager<ApplicationUser>.......".

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! The UserManager part works now. Is there any chance you could also help me get the Text value from the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the `textarea` problem.
The line should be like this instead:

```
<textarea asp-for="Posts.Text" id="mytextarea" rows="2" cols="80" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

I forgot to include `class="form-control"` and `name="txt"` was somehow causing a problem and needed to be omitted.